# angularjs directive doesn't update when scope value update

Tags: angularjs, directive

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
        'use strict';
        angular.module('myApp',[])
        .controller('TestCtrl',TestCtrl)
        .directive('trxTablePersonTd',trxTablePersonTd);

        function TestCtrl($scope){
          var vm = $scope.vm = this;
          vm.trxs = [
            {id:"1",acctKey:"2",persons:[{name:'peter',age:20},{name:'hank',age:23}]},
            {id:"2",acctKey:"3",persons:[{name:'Joe'},{name:'Jason'}]}
          ];
          $scope.changePerson = function(){
            vm.trxs[1]['persons']['age'] = 33;
            vm.trxs[1]['acctKey'] = 123;

          }
        }
        function trxTablePersonTd($compile){
            return{
              scope:{persons:'=persons'},
              restrict:'A',

              link:link,

              replace:false,
              //compile:compile
            }
            function compile(elem,attrs){
              return function(scope){
                var html = [];
                scope.persons.map(function(person,index){

                  html.push('<td>'+person.name+'</td>');
                  html.push('<td>'+person.age+'</td>');
                });

              }
            }
            function link(scope, elem, attrs){
              var html = [];

              if(scope.persons){
                scope.persons.map(function(person,index){

                  html.push('<td>'+person.name+'</td>');
                  html.push('<td>'+person.age+'</td>');
                });
              }
              elem.replaceWith(html.join(''));
              $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
            }

        }
      }());
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="changePerson()">change person</button>
    <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="trx in vm.trxs">

          <td>
            {{trx.id}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{trx.acctKey}}
          </td>
          <td trx-table-person-td  persons="trx.persons">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Blockquote

when I click the button the undefined age doesn't get update. can someone help me look at this problem

when I click the button the undefined age doesn't get update. can someone help me look at this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't properly update your collection in `$scope.changePerson` method. `persons` is also an array, it should like

```
$scope.changePerson = function () {
    vm.trxs[0]['persons'][0]['age'] = 33; //look ['persons'][0] 
    vm.trxs[0]['acctKey'] = 123;
}
```

As @Ed Staub suggest you need to **`$watch`** your collection to propagate further model change like

```
app.directive('trxTablePersonTd', function ($compile) {

    return {
        scope: { persons: '=persons' },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
        replace: false,
    }

    function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
        if (scope.persons) {
            scope.$watch('persons', function () {
                var html = scope.persons.map(function (person, index) {
                    return '<td>' + person.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + (person.age ? person.age : "") + '</td>';
                });

                elem.empty().append(html.join(''));
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

**Also if you don't have additional `html` except `td` in your directive, i think you don't need directive at all, just use `ng-repeat` like**

```
<td ng-repeat="person in trx.persons">
    <span>{{person.name}}</span>
    <span>{{person.age}}</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been waiting to see if someone would answer this better and more authoritatively than I can.  I believe the problem is because scope updates are not watched as deeply into data structures as your changes are.  I think you need to implement a deep watch ("watch by value") on `vm.trxs`.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope, scroll down to section on "Controllers and Scopes".